# Get each bootstrap-select values

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I have several [bootstrap-selects](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) on my page and I need to get all values they have before sending them to the server.

These selects are created or removed dinamically, then I have to use `.each()` function to get them. And here is the problem.

This is what I have :

```
// I have a select with a selected value of 1, and another with a selected value of 0

var foo = [];
$('.selectpicker').each(function(){
   foo.push($(this).val());
})

console.log(foo); // displays ["1","","","0","",""];
```

I guess the fact that this library hides the vanilla select and adds a button and a dropdown with the same class causes a problem, but I'm not sure.
Do you have any idea how I can fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to specify the element *as well as* the class, like so:

```
$('select.selectpicker').each(function() {
  foo.push($(this).val());
});
```

This will ensure that you're *only* fetching the values of actual `select` elements.